# Juniper SRX3600 Maximum Load Set Size

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx

What is the maximum size [`load set`](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos/topics/reference/command-summary/load.html) that a Juniper SRX3600, running Junos 11.4R7.5, can load and commit? I am attempting to add a 100,000+ line commit change and do not want to overwhelm the RE and cause node stability issues.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this question is important to answer?  It might be worth mentioning how many lines you think you need.  Also, purely FYI... [2000 lines doesn't seem to be out of the  question](http://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/Copying-and-pasting-almost-2000-lines/td-p/77924 "load set 2000 line configuration")

Comment: I am looking to commit a 100,000+ line change and do not want to overwhelm the RE causing node stability issues.

Comment: It might be worth opening a query with JTAC, you shouldn't need support contracts for a question like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After opening a JTAC case I was told there is not a known `load set` limit but that RE impact is to be expected. I can verify that I have been able to successfully load and commit a 250,000 line change on a Juniper SRX3600 running Junos 11.4R7.5 while under minimal load taking six minutes to verify and commit.